# Service Account connection to Google Calendar

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

I am attempting to connect to a **Google Calendar**, and have setup up a **Service Account** with **domain wide delegation**. 
I then downloaded the json p12 file, placed it on my web server and attempted to run the following code.

The goal is to have a php script return a list of events from a Google Calendar so they can be worked with.

When the code is executed, **$events** doesn't contain any of the items listed on the calendar, but a json object similar de the one below the php source.

Have I misread the documentation, am I missing something obvious?

Thank you kindly for the feedback,

Nate

```
<? require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $calendar = initCalendar();

    $events = $calendar->events->listEvents('primary');

    // Take from : https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list
    while(true) {
      foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        echo $event->getSummary();
      }
      $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    function initCalendar(){

        $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/my_downloaded_file.json';

        $client = new Google_Client();

        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.$KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();


        $client->setApplicationName('Calendar Sync');
        $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth       
        $client->setScopes([
            Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR
            , Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY
        ]);     


        $client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/api/events.php');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access


        $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);       

        return $calendar;   

    }


?>
```

Returned JSON

```
object(Google_Service_Calendar_Events)#58 (19) {
  ["collection_key":protected]=>
  string(5) "items"
  ["accessRole"]=>
  string(5) "owner"
  ["defaultRemindersType":protected]=>
  string(37) "Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminder"
  ["defaultRemindersDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["etag"]=>
  string(18) ""sdfsdfgsdfsf""
  ["itemsType":protected]=>
  string(29) "Google_Service_Calendar_Event"
  ["itemsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["kind"]=>
  string(15) "calendar#events"
  ["nextPageToken"]=>
  NULL
  ["nextSyncToken"]=>
  string(28) "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf="
  ["summary"]=>
  string(67) "user@domain.test"
  ["timeZone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
  ["updated"]=>
  string(24) "2018-09-20T10:17:37.161Z"
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["defaultReminders"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["items"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I'll edit

Comment: Dang it. It seems the issue was the calendar ID. If I use "primary" as id, no events are loaded, but if I enter the id of an existing calendar, all prints fine. I guess the "primary" keyword is not used when accessing using a service account. I guess it would make sense... Anyways, it works!

Comment: added and answer explaining why it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service account is s dummy user it is not your personal user.  it has its own Google calendar account.  When you supply `primary` for the calendar if it is the primary calendar for the current authenticated user which is the service account.

You can add new events to the service accounts calendar or share your calendar with the service account then you will need to supply the calendar id of your calendar inorder to access that data.